# Are these participants repeatedly measured?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have Likert items for a number of students learning Spanish and English at the same time.  I really need to compare the means for each (non-normal) variable to see which language is voted higher for variables such as "I watch TV in this language".

Now, these participants are clearly not matched pairs, they are the same people being tested under two conditions (Spanish or English).  Repeated measures refers to time differences.  Is the time idea essential or can I call my participants repeated measures?  If not, what are they, and what sort of test is indicated for comparing the means?

To anyone who responds, many thanks - I am a newbie

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking.  What is your research question?  Could you formulate things in terms of dependent and independent variables?  How does time come in?

Comment: Just to respond to your request for a test. In your case Wilcoxon's Signed-rank seems to be the appropriate choice if you'd like to compare question such as "I prefer to read news in Spanish" and "I prefer to read news in English."

Answer (score 1):

Peter is right of course.  Repeated measures from a given subject is a matched pair of sample variables from that given subject.  Repeated measures, matched samples, and within subjects designs are not synonyms but analytically the same processes tend to be used.  You can absolutely use a repeated measures/within subjects analysis on your data.  The variable that is standing in for time is 'language'.

Answer (score 0):

Odd as it seems, I think these participants *are* matched pairs. This is similar to a study in which both eyes of various people are studied - in which case the right eye would match with the left eye. The idea is that the variables are matched, not necessarily that the subjects are.